# return single object from unique_ptr vector in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I'm making a command applaction I have base class that other commands class inherate.

```cpp
struct BaseCommand {
public:
    virtual ~BaseCommand() {}
    int id = 0;
    std::string name = "Base Command";
    std::string description = "Base Command";
    BaseCommand();
    virtual std::string getName();
    virtual int getId();
    virtual std::string getDescription();
private:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
    
};
```

```cpp
class HelpCommand: public BaseCommand {
public:
    HelpCommand();
    std::string name = "help";
    std::string description = "output help";
    int id = 1;
    virtual std::string getName();
    int getId() {return this->id;}; 
    virtual std::string getDescription();
    
private:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
};
```

```cpp
class ProductCommand: public BaseCommand {
public:
    ProductCommand();
    std::string name = "prod";
    std::string description = "product";
    int id = 2;
    virtual std::string getName();
    int getId() {return this->id;};
    virtual std::string getDescription();
    
private:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
};
```

and in my main, I push my subclass to a vector. my goal is to get the command by its name how do I do that and get the only command and assign it to a variable

```cpp
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseCommand>> commands;
    // lett's push our commands...
    commands.emplace_back(new HelpCommand);
    commands.emplace_back(new ProductCommand);
    std::string command = 'prod';

    // what's the type should be for selectedCommand?
    ?? selectedCommand;

    for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); ++i) {
        if (commands[i]->getName() == command) {
             selectedCommand = commands[i];
        }
   }
```

I can't seem to determine which type should the `selectedCommand` be. please what I'm missing here?

I can't seem to determine which type should the `selectedCommand` be. please what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the goal of assigning it to `selectedCommand`? Is `selectedCommand` just supposed to be a reference to the object inside the vector or is it supposed to take over ownership of the object (and by doing so remove it from the vector)?

Comment: `commands.emplace_back(new HelpCommand);`: Please don't use `new` here. It will cause a memory leak if the `emplace_back` throws an exception. Use `commands.emplace_back(std::make_unique<HelpCommand>());` instead.

Comment: actually,  the selectedCommand will be assigned to a property in a class called CommandCreator, when selectedCommand made, I will use that selectedCommand and run its methods.

Comment: `Which type`? Probably a pointer to the closest common base class, like `std::unique_ptr<BaseCommand>`?

Comment: @Zymawy And who does own (i.e. determine the lifetime of) the object you created with `new`? Is it supposed to be the vector, meaning that `CommandCreator` is designed to not outlive it? Or is it supposed to be `CommandCreator` and the object should be removed from the vector? Or are they supposed to share ownership, in which case you might want a `shared_ptr` instead of a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind yes, but when I use it, it throws an error 
`Object of type 'std::unique_ptr<BaseCommand>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted`

Comment: Your derived classes have two of each member variable. When you access the objects through a pointer to `BaseCommand`, you get the members from `BaseCommand`.

Comment: @Zymawy you can only "move" `unique_ptr` outside of your vector: `selectedCommand = std::move(commands[i]);`

Comment: @molbdnilo, so how I can declare the correct type for `selectedCommand` and get the derived class? since all the derived classes have inherited BaseCommand?

Comment: my idea is to push all the commands class, to a vector. then when a command selected I will go and get it from the commands vector and start the command in one place in this case CommandCreatore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "override" member variables.

Your derived classes have two of each member variable with the same name; one in the base class and one in the derived class.
When you access the objects through a pointer to `BaseCommand`, you get the members from `BaseCommand` and not those from the dervied class.

Redesign so these are only members of the base, and make the accessors non-virtual:

```
struct BaseCommand {
public:
    virtual ~BaseCommand() {}
    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
    int getId() const { return id; }
    const std::string& getDescription() const { return description; }

protected:
    // Let only derived classes create base instances.
    BaseCommand(int id,
                const std::string& name,
                const std::string& description)
        : id(id), name(name), description(description)
    {}

private:
    int id = 0;
    std::string name = "Base Command";
    std::string description = "Base Command";

    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
};

class HelpCommand: public BaseCommand {
public:
    HelpCommand() : BaseCommand(1, "help", "output help") {}
private:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
};
class ProductCommand: public BaseCommand {
public:
    ProductCommand() : BaseCommand(2, "prod", "product") {}
private:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void run();
};
```

Comment: still I can't get the selected comamnd this the functoin that should return the selected command 
`void CommandCreator::findCommand(std::string commandName) {
    std::unique_ptr<BaseCommand> selectedCommand;
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); ++i) {
        if (commands[i]->getName() == commandName) {
            selectedCommand = commands[i];
        }
   }
    
    return selectedCommand;
}`

getting this `Object of type 'std::unique_ptr<BaseCommand>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted`

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot 
https://ibb.co/p3ypcfV

Comment: Yes, you can't copy a `unique_ptr`. You need to rethink the ownership.

Comment: any better you that can help me resolve my idea?

Comment: It's not clear what the idea is. What is the significance of `selectedCommand`? Why is it not just an index in your vector?

Comment: the idea is that I don't wanna run any command until is selected by the customer. once selected I will go and get it from the vector. then assigned it to a property in class, then run the run method for it only.

Comment: And you can do that with an index; `commands[selectedIndex]->run();`. Or you could set up a table and do `table[name]->run();`